# Import CSV and create Temp Table to store results

Tags: python, mysql

So, I've imported a CSV file, which could have any number of columns and rows. I'd like to store the results in a temporary Table, eg: "TEMP_30f3724fc226e058" instead of working off the CSV file across multiple pages.

I've got the below, but beyond that I'm unsure how to add what would essentially be an unknown amount of columns and rows. Any ideas would be amazing.

```
key = '30f3724fc226e058'
cursor = connection.cursor()
db_name = 'TEMP_{0}'.format(key)
cursor.execute('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE {0} (X INT)'.format(db_name))
... ?
```

Insert the data from the CSV, then I can pull that data at any point along the CSV import process. Thanks again,

Comment: [1] Read one row. [2] Count number of columns. [3] Create table. [4] Import remaining rows.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, thanks man, I reckon that'll do the trick. Have you got any examples for the creation of a TABLE that would have say 8 fields called 'column_1', 'column_2' etc ... A dynamic example for CREATE and INSERT would be even better. I can't find anything online that looks even close and can't quite wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The step are:

1. Read one row of the file, to get the number of columns.
2. Create a table with those number of columns.
3. Loop through the remaining file.

Something like this:

```
import csv
import time

column_count = 2 # Assume we have 2 columns, which is the minimum

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    # fetch the first row, grab the column length
    column_count = len(next(reader)) 

# Next, create the table:

table_name = 'sometable_{0}'.format(int(time.time()))

q = 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE {0} ('.format(table_name)
q += ', '.join('col_{0} VARCHAR(255)'.format(i) for i in range(column_count))
q += ');'

cur.execute(q)
cur.commit()

q = "INSERT INTO {0} VALUES (".format(table_name)
q += ', '.join(('%s ' * column_count).split())
q += ');'


# Now, populate it

with open('somefile.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        cur.execute(q, tuple(row))
        cur.commit()
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply @BurhanKhalid, I was knee-deep in Breaking Bad. Thanks so much for the above, after a bit of tossing around I got it rolling. Only as I was using a local sqlite3 database, otherwise your code is spot on. Thanks again!